# Laravel 5.1 save something in database with ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, laravel

I am building an application where users can upload projects. I am implementing a system where users can 'Like/Unlike' other projects. I am trying to use an AJAX call to save likes. Users are able to like projects on the detail page of a project (/projects/{id})

I have a table users, projects and likes. My plan is to save the likes in the likes table obviously so a record looks like this: id, user_id, project_id. In the future I can do a COUNT query and find out how many likes each project has, etc.

For some reason when I click on the like button my application gets stuck and keeps loading until it crashes.

My files:
Ajax call

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        console.log("js loaded");
        $('#likeform').on('submit', function(e) {
            console.log("like submitted");
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                url: $(this).parent().attr('action'),
                type: "post",
                data: {'_token': token, 'user_id': $('input[name=user_id]').val(), 'project_id': $('input[name=project_id]').val()},
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }
            })
        });
    });
```

My Form

```
  {!! Form::open(array('url'=>'projects/'.$project->id.'/like','method'=>'POST', 'id'=>'likeform')) !!}
    <input type="hidden" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    {!! Form::Submit('Like', array('class'=>'send-btn')) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

My Routes:

```
Route::get('/', 'LikeController@index');
Route::post('projects/{id}/like', 'LikeController@like');
```

My like function in the LikeController:

```
public function like()
{
    if(Request::ajax()) {
        $data = Input::all();
        print_r($data);die;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the browser console say something while loading? Did you check your laravel.log? Provide any kind of error will greatly improve your chances to get a proper answer.

Comment: There's nothing in my console. And I get no errors at all which is kinda annoying.

Comment: Weird. Anyway, I did not test your code, but you're trying to retrive an `action` attribute from your form while it doesn't have one. You did set an `url` instead. I'm not confident this is what you're looking for, but it's worth a try imo. Side note: building a form with the `Form` facade will automatically set an hidden `token` field, so there's no actually need to add to your form a second one.

Comment: Oh okay I was wondering why there are 2 hidden token fields. Now I know :)

Comment: `action` vs `url` was a nonsense. My bad. Still is quite strange you are not getting any error, at least within the server log.

Comment: My goals is to save something in my database and I don't really see where this is happening at the moment

Comment: I'm gonna switch to an answer cause we are getting out of room here.

Answer (score 0):

The

> gets stuck and keeps loading until it crashes

part may  be related to the fact that the ajax post expects some kind of response, but you are not responding at all in your controller. Try something like

```
public function like()
{
    if(Request::ajax()) {
        $data = Input::all();
        return Response::json([
                'error' => false,
                'insertedData' => $data
            ], 200);
    }
}
```

Remenber to `use Response` in your controller. Now you are returning something to the ajax call and you should be able to access `$data`

```
success: function(data){
            alert(data.insertedData);
         }
```

Are you experiencing the same behaviour? If not you can move on and perform the actual db insert.

Comment: I've tried your answer and unfortuantely I am still experiencing the same behaviour

Comment: @MoussaChaabar Ok, that's getting even more weird. You should try to test your code in developer mode and try to understand where/who fails. A couple of breakpoints within your ajax call it's a good start. Still I don't get why you are not getting any error. Can u try to set an `error` callback into your ajax, something like `error: function(data){ console.log(data);}`. At least that should tell us if the ajax call is actually performed.